# Неправильно выводится число

Tags: javascript, математика

```
var a='51';
var alen=a.length;

for(i in a){
    var index=alen-(i+1);
}
```

Нужно получить каждую цифру в числе 'a' начиная с конца, она, по идее, должна быть в a[index]. При первой итерации в index получается 1 - всё правильно. При второй откуда-то появляется -9. Где ошибка?

Comment: Конструкция `for (i in a)` принципиально неправильна для строк. Можете сами посмотреть, что будет в `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Но почему не сделать проще?

```
'51'.split('').reverse().forEach( function(v){ console.log(v) } )
```

Answer (score 2):

Задачу можно решать разными способами. Вот наиболее простая на мой взгляд исправленная версия вашей программы.

```
var a='51';
var alen=a.length;

for (var i = alen-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var index = a.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перевернуть строку?
Проще так:

```js
var a = '51';

var reverseArr = a.split('').reverse(); // ['1', '5']
var reverseStr = reverseArr.join(''); // '15'

console.log(reverseStr, reverseArr);
```